# AngularJS - Reset array on cancel has flickering effect when scope refreshes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm very new to Angular (not Javascript), so I apologize if I don't use the correct terms/procedure.

I have a model like so:

```
BuyingGroups: {
   availableBuyingGroups: [
      obj1: {
         ID: XX,
         Title: XX
      },
      ....
   ],
   affiliatedBuyingGroups: [
      obj1: {
         ID: XX,
         Title: XX
      },
      ....
   ]
}
```

There are (2) panes (think of them as list boxes). A user can add an object from the left pane to the right, and vice versa. Basically I'm just moving objects from one group to the other.

On load, I take those (2) lists, and use `angular.copy` to copy those to another *static* list, so as not to affect the original (I read that angular uses the context if you don't use `angular.copy`).

On reset (cancel button), I reset the original lists back to the copies (to keep the original state). **The problem is on the cancel button event, the list seems to "duplicate" itself for about .3 seconds, which flickers on the pane, then reverts back to it's original state (on page load).**

I've attempted to clear out the array, set a timeout, etc, but nothing seems to have an effect. Is there (or should there be) a more efficient, better way of doing this? Perhaps I do not fully understand how angular binds to the `$scope` on changes?

*self = $scope  (fyi)*

```
self.companyBuyingGroups = response.data.BuyingGroups;
self.staticCompanyBuyingGroupsModel = angular.copy(self.companyBuyingGroups);
self.staticCompanyAffiliationsModel = angular.copy(self.companyAffiliations);
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- affiliated instance -->
<li ng-repeat="group in companyBuyingGroups.affiliatedBuyingGroups">
    .....
</li>
```

**Reset button function**

```
self.resetBuyingGroupsForm = function () {
     self.companyBuyingGroups.affiliatedBuyingGroups = [];
     self.companyBuyingGroups.availableBuyingGroups = [];

     //setTimeout(function () {
          self.companyBuyingGroups.affiliatedBuyingGroups = angular.copy(self.staticCompanyBuyingGroupsModel.affiliatedBuyingGroups);
          self.companyBuyingGroups.availableBuyingGroups = angular.copy(self.staticCompanyBuyingGroupsModel.availableBuyingGroups);
          //self.companyBuyingGroups = angular.copy(self.staticCompanyBuyingGroupsModel);
     //}, 50)
}
```

---

**EDIT**

I have tried to clear the arrays prior to reset, along w/ not clearing them. Also my arrays are super small (less than 50 objects).

To explain more of the "flickering", on the cancel function, the right pane seems to add the copy (instead of using the original). Meaning, if the original list had 3 items, and I added an item from the left pane (making it 4), then the cancel function was called, the right pane shows 7 items for about .3s, then reverts back to 3 items (which was the original).

[image]

Comment: Why you clear arrays before setting them default value using angular.copy?

Comment: "...then reverts back to it's original state (on page load)...." Are you reloading the page on cancel? A plunk would help debug the problem easier.

Comment: @NMittal No sorry I'm not reloading the page at all.

Comment: @Viktor I was attempting to do everything that I could think of, I didn't say it was the right thing to do

Comment: Not entirely sure, but did you give a try doing this angular.copy(self.staticCompanyBuyingGroupsModel.affiliatedBuyingGroups, self.companyBuyingGroups.affiliatedBuyingGroups ); instead of doing  self.companyBuyingGroups.affiliatedBuyingGroups = angular.copy(self.staticCompanyBuyingGroupsModel.affiliatedBuyingGroups); ?

Comment: @NMittal Unfortunately this has the same effect. Neat though, didn't know you could right it like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should append `track by group.ID` to your `ng-repeat` expression, this will allow AngularJS to reuse the DOM when the list resets, which will fix the issue.

When you reset your list, Angular first needs to remove every item from the DOM (since they are not in the array anymore), then add them back. Using `track by group.ID` will allow `ngRepeat` to track them by ID instead of reference, and it now knows which item to remove and which to keep.

Comment: OMG I read up on this a week ago but didn't know the real benefit for using this. Thanks so much!!!!!

Comment: Cheer, I’d recommend Ben Nadel’s article about this: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2556-using-track-by-with-ngrepeat-in-angularjs-1-2.htm

Comment: Yeah I was going to ask the benefits. Apprec the blog link - funny I had read this exact same blog post, but apparently didn't sink in enough.

Answer (score 0):

**#1**

It probably blinks because you first empty the arrays.

Try commenting out the first two assignments to `=[]` in you Reset function, and keep only two `angular.copy` assignments.

**#2**

If you have huge lists that might take time to be rerendered, consider comparing the arrays model in controller to the initial one -  to find and keep those list items that are already rendered, and add/remove only the non-corresponding ones.

Comment: Unfortunately I had tried multiple options, including not emptying the arrays. And my original arrays are less than 50 objects.